# Dirichlet process/Chinese restaurant process for clustering in R

Tags: r, clustering, dirichlet-process

I recently read a [fascinating article](http://blog.echen.me/2012/03/20/infinite-mixture-models-with-nonparametric-bayes-and-the-dirichlet-process/) describing methods for clustering data without assuming a fixed number of clusters.

The article even includes some sample code, in a mix of Ruby, Python, and R.  However, the meat of the analysis is performed using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/dev/index.html)'s [Dirichlet Process Gaussian Mixture Model](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/dev/modules/mixture.html) to actually find clusters in some sample data taken from McDonald's menu.

Obviously, this a a great excuse to learn some more python, but I'm lazy and would like to find a ready-made R package that can take a dataframe and return clusters, in a manner similar to the [kmeans](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kmeans.html) function.  [A quick search on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html) reveals the packages [dpmixsim](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dpmixsim/index.html) and [profdpm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/profdpm/index.html).  Any suggestions for the best place to start?

Comment: Also http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DPpackage/ which has Dirichlet process clustering I think, and http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bayesm/ has some DP stuff, don't remember what.

Comment: Whoever voted down- could you please leave a comment?

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted but I wanted to comment that one can simply add the number of clusters to the likelihood of the mixture distribution (often solved using E-M algorithm). It appears from your problem a Gaussian mixture model is assumed ( I don't know how the Dirichlet process fits in).  There are some excellent books on mixture distributions.  I recommend two by McLachlan. Finite Mixture Models (Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics) [Hardcover] 
Geoffrey McLachlan (Author), David Peel (Author) and

Comment: Mixture Models (Statistics: A Series of Textbooks and Monographs) [Hardcover] G. J. McLachlan (Author), K. E. Basford (Author)

Comment: @Michael: maximum likelihood with a varying number of (gaussien) clusters — how do you make it not to overlearn, especially if the cluster width is a parameters as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at this more carefully, and the package [bayesm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bayesm/index.html) has *rDPGibbs* which does "Density Estimation with Dirichlet Process Prior and Normal Base", a kind of Dirichlet clustering. [DPpackage](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DPpackage/) has *DPdensity* which looks similar. I haven't tried these packages myself, so I have no idea how well they work in practice. Details such as parameterization of the normal base and the possibility to set hyperpriors for the DP parameter may be significant.

Comment: `DPpackage` is orphaned on CRAN as of August 2019 it looks like